# Get Value From Windows.location.href

Tags: jquery, html

I have pass value from `windows.location.href` like

```
window.location.href = 'index.html#one?narrat='+narration;
```

now i want to get this value from `"index"` page but how.

How i can get this value in index page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific question, this will give you the value of `narat`...

```
var narat = location.href.substr(location.href.search("\\?")).split("=")[1];
```

or even simpler...

```
var narat = location.href.split("narat=")[1];
```

If you are adding more variables to the querystring then it will need parsing differently.

Answer (score -1):

If i also understood your question right .

```
var loc = 'index.html#one?narrat='+narration;
window.location.href = 'index.html#one?narrat='+narration;
```

now you can acces this variable